# Get "part of speech" for a Spanish word

Tags: computational-linguistics, parts-of-speech, spanish, resource-request

I do a little linguistics as a hobby while working of my own software development projects. I am wondering if there is a database or online api where I can easily establish the possible "parts of speech" for a given word from within my code. So for example:

```
getPartOfSpeech("papa")
```

returns `["noun"]`. And if a word has multiple parts of speech associated with it then multiple values are returned by the function with the most common association listed first. I program in python put can a number of other languages also.

Comment: You could probably use an aspell or hunspell dictionary as the basis for a destemmer. Then you could use Wiktionary data for the base word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POS-tagging is more complicated than giving it an input word - and get the POS tag as an output. This is because of the ambiguity of the language itself (for example, the word "mine" can be a verb, but also a noun). So, it depends from the context in which it appears within the sentence. The best way to do this, is to give a whole sentence as an input, and get the POS tags of each word as an output, and then get the tag you need from the sentence.

For a POS tagger, you can use the [Stanford CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) pipeline, which also includes a POS tagger (they have for Spanish as well). As far as I know, [NLTK also has Spanish support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732465/nltk-tagging-spanish-words-using-a-corpus), so you might use that toolkit as well.

Another thing you can use is [BabelNet](http://babelnet.org/) "a multilingual lexicalized semantic network and ontology". By using their API, you can get a lot of information about a word (including the POS tag).